# Optimizing slow multi cursor approach?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor

I designed a workflow, that although functional, is very slow and prone to errors. I am sure there is a better approach, but I cannot wrap my head around it. The environment is ArcGIS arcpy (Python 3), the data is located in a SDE database.

The task is to fill the initially empty table (FIN TABLE), with data from the feature class (featureIN). I need to group features with the same Field1, 2, 3, and write back the received GlobalID into ProcessID.

My approach is to

1. Dissolve based on Field1, 2, 3
2. Use a SearchCursor on the resulted dissolved features
3. Look up the attributes (Attr1, 2) from featureIN. Keep Last. (SearchCursor)
4. Write the data to FIN TABLE (InsertCursor)
5. Catch the GlobalID (SearchCursor)
6. Write it back to featureIN (UpdateCursor)

[image: Workflow with example data]

With that workflow I manage to process 10 rows/s, which takes too long given the large dataset I have.

Is there a better approach? How can this be optimized?

EDIT:
Here is the rough workflow in python:

```
INfc = 'featureIN.shp' 
dissTMPfc = 'DISSOLVE.shp'
OUTtb = 'FIN TABLE'
dm1 = {'Field1': 1,'Field2': 2,'Field3': 3,'Attr1': 4,'Attr2': 5 } # FieldMap

#### Step 1 Dissolve based on Field1, 2, 3 ####
fieldsDIS = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']
arcpy.Dissolve_management(INfc, dissTMPfc, ';'.join(fieldsDIS), "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")

#### Step 2 Use a SearchCursor on the resulted dissolved features ####
cursorDIS = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dissTMPfc, fieldsDIS)
for row in cursorDIS:

    # build where clause for each row
    whereClause = ""
    i = 0
    for field in fieldsDIS:
        if i > 0: whereClause = whereClause + " AND "
        if row[i] is not None:
            whereClause = whereClause + field + " = '" + str(row[i]) + "'"
        else:
            whereClause = whereClause + field + " IS NULL"
        i = i + 1

    ### Step 3 Look up the attributes (Attr1, 2) from featureIN. Keep Last.
    cursorIN = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(INfc, fieldsIN, whereClause )
    updRow = []
    for row2 in cursorIN:
        for key in dm1.keys():
            updRow.append(row2[dm1[key]])

    ### Step 4 Write the data to FIN TABLE (InsertCursor)
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OUTtb, fieldsOUT) as cursorTAB:
        objectid = cursorTAB.insertRow(updRow)

    ### Step 5 Catch the GlobalID (SearchCursor)
    searchFields = ['OBJECTID', 'GlobalID']
    whereClause2 = 'OBJECTID = {0}'.format(objectid)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OUTtb, searchFields, whereClause2) as searchCursor:
        for row3 in searchCursor:
            globalid = row3[searchFields.index('GlobalID')]
            f.write(globalid)

    ### Step 6 Write GlobalID back to featureIN (UpdateCursor)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(INfc, ['ProcessID'], whereClause) as cursorINupd:
        for row in cursorINupd:
            row[0] = globalid
            cursorINupd.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: You need to add the code so we can see exactly what you are doing. Are you using cursors inside cursors? Try using dictionaries instead

Comment: +1 @BERA. you can also check [this post](https://community.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries) on geonet to see this at work!

Comment: I added the code. I had to quickly adapt it, so it is untested. Yes, I am using cursor inside cursor. Will dictionaries not grow too large for this task? I will read through the post! Thanks!

Comment: You're using the variable `row` at multiple levels of nesting. You don't provide enough details on row counts to provide useful feedback. I once cached 3.6Gb of vertices in a dictionary using the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing ArcPy.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the hint with the variable.

Comment: @BERA I have 200000 rows in the featureIN. 50000 in Dissolve. I am right now trying the approach with multiple dictionaries and trying to do without nested cursors.

Comment: Yes, I need SHAPE@XY for the FIN TABLE (forgot to add it to the example)

Comment: Is `GlobalID` a GUID field? Does it get automatically populated when you insert the new row? And so you're looking for the new GlobalID created when you insert the row?

Comment: Yes, that is currect, it is automatically populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making use of cursors within cursors, as well as appling sql queries to those cursor which can slow down the process exponentially. Your dissolve also appears to be unnecessary as it appears to be used to get unique IDs. I suggest making use of dictionaries to store information. This task can be completed with four cursors run one at a time.

1. Search input table and create dictionary of field values key to attributes
2. Update out table with dictionary and update cursor
3. Create dictionary of field values and guids in out table with search cursor
4. Update input table with guids with dictionary and update cursor

Example code (untested):

```
INfc = 'featureIN.shp'
OUTtb = 'FIN TABLE'

#get last attributes in input table, store in dictionary
di = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (INfc, ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Attr1', 'Attr2']) as curs:
    for fld1, fld2, fld3, attr1, attr2 in curs:
        #update dict with key and attributes
        di [(fld1, fld2, fld3)] = (attr1, attr2)

#insert into out table keys, values
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (OUTtb, ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Attr1', 'Attr2']) as curs:
    #iterate stored value in dict
    for (fld1, fld2, fld3), (attr1, attr2) in di.items ():
        #create and insert row
        row = [fld1, fld2, fld3, attr1, attr2]
        curs.insertRow (row)

#search cursor to get new IDs generated when inserting row
di = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (OUTtb, ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'GlobalID']) as curs:
    fld1, fld2, fld3, guid in curs:
        #update dict with key and guid
        di [(fld1, fld2, fld3)] = guid

#update pid in table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (INfc, ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'ProcessID']) as curs:
    for fld1, fld2, fld3, pid in curs:
        #get id
        pid = di [(fld1, fld2, fld3)]
        #update row
        row = (fld1, fld2, fld3, pid)
        curs.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I was looking for! I forgot to mention it in the initial task, but I will need to add the dissolve step, as I need the shape@xy.

Comment: @Marcus if you want to be real fancy you can average each key’s x’s and y’s for you ‘dissolved’ xy without doing an actual dissolve.